# How to plot vectors orthogonal to quadmesh?

Tags: r, rgl

I am trying to use the `rgl` package in R to plot unit vectors orthogonal to each cell in a quadmesh. I've used [this page](https://mdsumner.github.io/geo-comp-graphics-oghub/the-mesh3d-format.html#quads) for a bit of guidance, and currently have plotted a quadmesh surface and some placeholder vectors using `arrow3d`, but I'd like to get these vectors to be orthogonal to the cell they're contained within and to all be the same length (e.g. length of 1). Does anyone know how to get the proper endpoint to put into `arrow3d` to satisfy this condition, or have a different approach?

```
library(raster)
library(rgl)
library(quadmesh)

m <- matrix(c(seq(0, 0.5, length = 5), 
              seq(0.375, 0, length = 4)), 3)
x <- seq(1, nrow(m)) - 0.5
y <- seq(1, ncol(m)) - 0.5
r <- raster(list(x = x, y = y, z = m))

qm <- quadmesh(r)
image(r)
op <- par(xpd = NA)
text(t(qm$vb), lab = 1:ncol(qm$vb)) #Plot index numbers for vertices
```

[image]

```
vrts<- list(c(9,10,14,13),
            c(10,11,15,14),
            c(11,12,16,15),
            c(5,6,10,9),
            c(6,7,11,10),
            c(7,8,12,11),
            c(1,2,6,5),
            c(2,3,7,6),
            c(3,4,8,7)) #Index for vertices of each raster cell starting from bottom left and moving to the right

shade3d(qm, col = "firebrick")
axes3d()
title3d(xlab="X", ylab="Y", zlab="Z")
for (i in 1:9) {
  row_number<- floor((i-1)/3)+1
  col_number<- ((i-1)%%3)+1
  p<- apply(qm$vb[1:3,  vrts[[i]]], mean, MARGIN = 1) #get current xyz position of raster cell
  rgl.spheres(x = p[1], y = p[2], z = p[3], r=0.1) #Plot points
  p0<- c(x[col_number], y[row_number],p[3]) #arrow start point
  p1<- c(x[col_number],y[row_number],p[3]+1) #arrow end point
  arrow3d(p0, p1) #Plot arrow
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is tricky. The fundamental insights are that:

1. Each square in the mesh can be thought of as a plane
2. Each plane can be defined by a formula z = **a**x + **b**y + **c**
3. The coefficients **a**, **b** and **c** can be found by running a linear regression on the 4 vertices than lie at the corners of each square.
4. The vector [**-a**, **-b**, **1**] is normal to the plane
5. The vector [**-a**, **-b**, **1**] / sqrt(**a²** + **b²** + **1²**) has length 1
6. The arrow bases are at the midpoint of each square
7. The arrow tips are at the bases of each square *plus* the vector [**-a**, **-b**, **1**] / sqrt(**a²** + **b²** + **1²**)

To implement this, we first define a couple of helper functions:

```r
midpoints <- function(x) diff(x)/2 + x[-length(x)]

centers_from_vertices <- function(v) {
  apply(apply(v, 1, midpoints), 1, midpoints)
}
```

Now we can create lists of x, y, z points for the vertices and the center points like this:

```r
vertices <- lapply(asplit(qm$vb, 1), `dim<-`, value = dim(m) + 1)
centres  <- lapply(vertices, centers_from_vertices)
```

Rather than having to count all the vertices and create a list belonging to each square, we can automate the process and have the indices of the vertices for each square in a list.

```r
index <- matrix(seq(prod(dim(m) + 1)), nrow = nrow(m) + 1, byrow = TRUE)

indices <- unlist(lapply(seq(dim(m)[1]), function(i) {
  lapply(seq(dim(m)[2]), function(j) {
    index[0:1 + i, 0:1 + j]
    })
  }), recursive = FALSE)
```

Now we can get the end-points of each arrow using the insights above:

```r
ends <- lapply(asplit(sapply(indices, function(i) {
  co <- coef(lm(z~x+y,  as.data.frame(lapply(vertices, c))[c(i),]))
  co <- -c(co[2], co[3], z = -1)
  co/sqrt(sum(co^2))
  }), 1), c)

ends <- Map(`+`, centres[1:3], ends)
```

Finally, we can draw the result:

```r
shade3d(qm, col = "firebrick")
axes3d()
title3d(xlab="X", ylab="Y", zlab="Z")
rgl.spheres(x = centres$x, y = centres$y, z = centres$z, r = 0.1)

for(i in 1:9) {
  arrow3d(c(centres$x[i], centres$y[i], centres$z[i]),
          c(ends$x[i], ends$y[i], ends$z[i]))
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks again Allan! Below @user2554330 brought up that the mesh may not actually be planar, and I can get some more distorted looking meshes by changing the value (e.g. m<- matrix(c(0.8,0.2,0.3, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, -1, 0.4,1),nrow=3)). Still even with that it looks roughly orthogonal but I'm not certain if it truly is.

Comment: @ailich, I think Allan's suggestion of using linear regression to find an approximating plane is a great idea.  Then if your mesh is approximately planar, you'll get a good answer, and if it's exactly planar, you'll get the exact answer.  One reason things might not *look* planar is if the axes aren't all scaled equally:  for example, visually I'd say your Z axis has wider spacing than X and Y (though this might be an illusion).

Comment: I was about to say the same as @user2554330 - the `lm` method gives the best approximation to a plane from a given set of 4 vertices even if they aren't co-planar. I assumed that each face of the mesh had to be planar. They certainly look planar, even in your new example.

Answer (score 2):

The `rgl:::showNormals()` function does this.  It's an internal function, used for debugging, and it plots the normals that are included in the mesh object, at each vertex.

There are a couple of issues for using this function with your data.  First, being an internal function, it's subject to change without notice.  So I'd make a copy of it and work with that.

Second, it plots the `normals` component of the mesh, and your mesh doesn't have one.  You can use the `rgl::addNormals()` function to add normals, and then it will work.  For example,

```
qmn <- addNormals(qm)
rgl:::showNormals(qmn)
```

[image: screenshot]

If you want the normals to point up, you can say `qmn$normals <- -qmn$normals` before plotting.

The third issue is that it uses the ugly `"lines"` type of arrow.  But if you've got a copy of the function, you could modify that.

The fourth issue is that the arrows are at the vertices, not the centers.  If you really want them at the centers, you'll need to calculate normals there.  Normals to a pair of vectors are calculated using the cross product (e.g. `rgl:::xprod()`), but you'll have to decide which pair of vectors to use.  `rgl` doesn't force quads to be planar; I don't know if `quadmesh` does.  This means that you might have more than one choice for the normal to the quad.

Comment: Thanks, perhaps connecting the diagonals of each cell would work as the two vector to calculate the cross product of?

Comment: Yes, that's a possibility.  Given you're working with square cells, it's probably identical to @AllanCameron's solution.  In general I don't think it would be.